# How can I replace a comma character in a CSV ONLY when included between " "

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, centos

I have a csv file which contains both words and amounts. When the amount is > 999 the number is enclosed within " " in order to differentiate the comma character used as thousand separator by the comma used as field separator, like this:

```
black, "1,340.00", brown, white, 150.00, blue
apple, 10.00, bread, coffee, "1,850.00", juice
cat, dog, 995.00, tiger, "2,450.00"
```

I wish to remove the comma ONLY where it's enclosed between " ", leaving the other comma (field separators), and also remove the " ".
The output of the new csv should be like this:

```
black, 1340.00, brown, white, 150.00, blue 
apple, 10.00, bread, coffee, 1850.00, juice 
cat, dog, 995.00, tiger, 2450.00
```

I played around with sed and awk but I'm not sure about the best way to achieve it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F\" '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/,/,"",$i)} 1' OFS="" input.csv
black, 1340.00, brown, white, 150.00, blue
apple, 10.00, bread, coffee, 1850.00, juice
cat, dog, 995.00, tiger, 2450.00
```

#### How it works

- `-F\"`

  This tells awk to use double-quotes as the field separator.
- `for (i=2; i<=NF; i=i+2) gsub(/,/,"",$i)`

  Every even field is a field in double-quotes.  For those even fields, we remove commas.

  *This only works because we chose `"` as the field separator.*
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.
- `OFS=""`

  This tells awk to use an empty string as the field separator on output.  This has the effect of removing the quotes.

Comment: Nicely done; just in case someone has the same misconception that I originally had: despite targeting only _even_-indexed fields, this solution actually _is_ column-agnostic, because `"` (rather than `,`) is used as the field separator.

Comment: Yup, got the upvote from me too though I'd have preferred to see the OFS initialization code at the front of the script before OFS is used (`awk -v OFS= 'script'`) rather than at the back of it after OFS is used (`awk 'script' OFS=""`).

Comment: MarcoFalzone, I'm glad it worked for you.  @EdMorton, your answer also has my +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -E 's/"([^"]+),([^"]+)"/\1\2/g' file
black, 1340.00, brown, white, 150.00, blue
apple, 10.00, bread, coffee, 1850.00, juice
cat, dog, 995.00, tiger, 2450.00
```

The above will only work for amounts under `999,999.99` (as shown in the sample input/output) since it can only remove one comma from each number.

This will work for any number:

```
awk '{while ( match($0,/([^"]*)("[^"]+")(.*)/,a) ) { gsub(/[",]/,"",a[2]); $0 = a[1] a[2] a[3] } }1' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), with other awks it'd use 3 calls to substr() instead.

[@John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38779300/1745001) is the more sensible, concise approach if you can have multiple commas in a field though.